# Забрать связанные записи

Tags: yii2, relation

Здравствуйте.
Начал переписывать проект с Yii1 на Yii2.
Дошел до связей моделей и недоумеваю. Неужели теперь нельзя за один запрос забрать все связанные записи и разложить по связанным моделям?

Пример. Есть таблица users и у нее связь на роль (таблица roles по users.role_id). Я хочу сразу приджойнить roles и забрать роль юзера.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord  
{
    // объявляю связь
    public function getRole() 
    {
         return $this->hasOne(Role::className(), ['id'=>'role_id']);
    }
}

...

// затем хочу получить юзера с ролью
$user = User::find()->joinWith('role')->one();
```

Здесь выполнится запрос:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `roles` ON `users`.`role_id` = `roles`.`id`
```

Затем при обращении `$user->role` выполняется новый запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `roles` WHERE `id`=1
```

Но зачем? Я ведь уже приджойнил нужную таблицу и осталось лишь забрать нужное поле оттуда (как в yii1).

Где-то видел мнение, что в yii1 это приводило к нечитаемому запросу и постобработке данных и бла-бла-бла. Но какое кому дело до читаемости запросов при использовании ActiveRecord?

В общем, основной вопрос, как мне сразу забрать связанные записи? Чтоб обращаться $model->someRelation без доп. запросов.

П.с. Вариант создать в класс User поле `public $role_name` и в запросе выбирать `roles.name AS role_name` не рассматриваю, потому как в будущем будет более 10 джойнов с разными вложенностями и прописывать везде public свойства неразумно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем примерную реализацию можно посмотреть здесь:
https://github.com/yii2tech/ar-eagerjoin

Общая суть такая: переопределить в ActiveRecord метод populateRecord, который разбирает результат запроса для создания модели.
Получается в select добавим `SomeRelation.column AS SomeRelation__column`, затем в populateRecord разбираем столбец и понимаем, что он относится к связи SomeRelation и его свойству column.

Answer (score 0):

В Yii 2 JOIN используется для выборок с условиями (например пользователи с какой-то ролью).

Если хотите использовать связанные модели, сначала делается запрос к основной таблице модели. Затем по связанному полю к связанной модели через IN. По производительности это получается быстрее чем LEFT JOIN. Что видно в дебагере.

В вашем случае через  relation будет так.

```
$user = User::find()->with('role')->one();
```

И уже потом, в представлении, вы обращаетесь к свойствам как

```
$user->role->role_id
```

А через LEFT JOIN вот так

```
$user = User::find()->select("*.role, *.user")->joinWith('role')->one();
```

Comment: Может в этом простом запросе это и будет производительнее. Но, как я писал выше, у меня будут запросы с 10-15 джойнами и от них не избавится, потому что про связанным данным будут фильтрации, сортировки, группировки и т.д.

Comment: Тогда только через DAO.